# Control windows service using WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, windows-services

I am creating windows service, which must be able to receive commands from client located on other computer.

So far it seemed like using WCF for comunication is a good idea. However I am unable to pass any argument to my service on server side. All tutorials on WCF show only basic methods, which do not interact witch windows service.

Is there any way how to communicate with windows service? - Be able to call methods, that return some data. Using WCF it feels like I am only a step away. I can call methods on server and getting data back. I am however not able to access parameters of the service to modify them.

**Basicaly what I want is to have a thread running in the windows service doing periodiccaly some actions, and to be able to remotely interact with it (it is not enough to pass only number code, I need to be able to pass at least string (preferably custom type) and get answer (string or custom type))**

Thanks

Comment: I believe you'll need at least two threads.  One to handle the work the service does, and another to respond to requests via WCF (socket, named pipe, tcp, etc...)  Maybe if you post an example of what you're doing, more specific answers could be posted.

Comment: Example: I have windows service that start automaticcaly on start of the machine. This service creates a thread that periodiccaly does some actions. I want to be able to modify actions of the thread remotely (eg. to add a file into list of files this thread is working with) and to get status of the service (the list of files). So far I have WCF hosted in windows service on server side, but from this WCF service I am not able to communicate with windows service on the same machine - I thought I would be easy to communicate with service hosting WCF from that WCF. I could interact via File but...

Answer (score 0):

If you can pass the number you can modify the service contract to use a (custom) data contract including strings and also more complex types. You need to check [DataContract] for more those complex types.

This link covers the basics: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/653493/WCF-Hosting-with-Windows-Service

It starts with creating the service and creating an installer for the windows service.

Starting with the Fourth module there it is explained how to complete coding on the client side.
You need to expose the service metadata for service reference to complete programming the client.

If you have the metadata exchange, you can also check if you can find the hosted WCF service with tools like the WCFtestclient.

Comment: Are your WCF Service Host and WCF Test Client running and providing the expected results?

Comment: I was able to do this - host WCF in windows service and communicate with it from client. However I need to interact with windows service in order change some of its parameters. Using given sample I am able to respond to client, but not to modify underlying (or another) windows service.